# Change line border color in geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

How does one change the color of the line border in `geom_smooth()`?

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

[image]

It should look something like this:

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23406820/680068

Answer (score 5):

One way is to plot wider, black lines first. Note that you need to add `group = cyl` for this to work properly.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group = cyl, color = cyl)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, size = 2.5, color = "black", se = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]

Comment: What if one wants to change the colour of the OUTER border of the area of the confidence interval?

Comment: @Dag add `+ geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", fill = NA, color = "black")`